# PHP foreach banlist only checks last line of file

Tags: php

I have a simple website and I would like to have the ability to ban some users from accessing it by using PHP. Here is the method I have tried:

```
    $banlist = file('ipbans.txt');
    foreach ($banlist as $line)
    {
        if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $line) {
            die; 
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, this approach only causes the script to terminate (`die`) for whatever IP address is on the last line of `ipbans.txt`. Particularly, the behavior I expect is that every connection from an IP address on any line of `ipbans.txt` would `die`, but this is not the case.

My website is too remote to be targeted for a great amount of harassment, and I don't expect to ever ban that many IP addresses. Thus the problems that would arise from having thousands of lines in `ipbans.txt` are not a concern in this case. However, if there is a technically more efficient approach that is also easy to implement, I am open to investigating it. (As long as it's still a PHP solution - I can't implement e.g. `.htaccess` bans.)

In any case, what is the reason for this last-line-only behavior, and how can I fix this?

Comment: try this code: $banlist = file('ipbans.txt');
 $status = true;
 foreach ($banlist as $line) {
  if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == trim($line)) {
    $status = false;
    break;
  }
}
if(!$status) {
  die;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that PHP's `file` method includes the line endings for each line. Note this line from the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

> Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES is used.

You need to either use `trim($line)`:

```php
    $banlist = file('ipbans.txt');
    foreach ($banlist as $line)
    {
        if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == trim($line)) {
            die; 
        }
    }
```

or `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`:

```php
    $banlist = file('ipbans.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach ($banlist as $line)
    {
        if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $line) {
            die; 
        }
    }
```

**Updated to include an explanation**

When you read the contents of a file, it reads all characters including invisible things like line endings (EOF). Let's say you had the following file:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx
yy.yy.yy.yy
zz.zz.zz.zz
```

Now, let's use `\n` to represent a line ending character. When you read this into an array using `file`, the array contents will be:

```php
[
    "xx.xx.xx.xx\n",
    "yy.yy.yy.yy\n",
    "zz.zz.zz.zz"
]
```

Now, if the remote address is `xx.xx.xx.xx`, you can see the comparison to `xx.xx.xx.xx\n` will be false. Luckily, using `trim($line)` will remove any new line or white space characters from the beginning or end of the string. You can also use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag to tell the `file` method to trim each line for you when reading it into the array.

Comment: I should also mention that using `trim` is really a best practice when reading contents from a file, unless you need to keep leading/trailing white space for some reason. You don't want something like an extra space at the end of a line throwing off a comparison, which is something you can spend hours trying to track down later.